# Autowiring inside abstract class made for mapstruct

Tags: java, spring, rest, abstract-class, mapstruct

I am trying to build a REST Controller using Spring. To format the data for readability and more integration, I have used Mapstruct. Here's how I wrote Mapper.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class DeviceDataMapper {

@Autowired
DeviceService deviceService;

public static DeviceDataMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DeviceDataMapper.class);

@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "deviceId", target = "iddevice"),
    @Mapping(source = "deviceName", target = "name")
})
public abstract TODevice deviceToTODevice(DeviceData device);

public DeviceData toDeviceToDeviceData(TODevice toDevice){
    DeviceData deviceData = new DeviceData();
    deviceData.setDeviceId(toDevice.getIddevice());
    deviceData.setDeviceName(toDevice.getName());
    deviceData.setDeviceTemplateId(toDevice.getDeviceTemplateId());
    try {
deviceData.setDeviceTemplateName(deviceService.findDeviceTemplateById(toDevice.getDeviceTemplateId()).getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return deviceData;
}}
```

The API Controller function looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{deviceId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody DeviceData get(@PathVariable int deviceId) {
    DeviceData deviceData=new DeviceData();
    try {
        deviceData =    DeviceDataMapper.INSTANCE.toDeviceToDevice(deviceService.findOne(deviceId));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return deviceData;
}
```

The output deviceData returns fine except for one detail. I couldn't get to this function `deviceService.findDeviceTemplateById(toDevice.getDeviceTemplateId()` (where deviceService is autowired). The error stack trace shows me NullPointerException. So I am wondering whether is there any general rule about the accessibility of the autowired resources in abstract class? Or is the way I am instantiating that makes this function inaccessible? What should I change to make it work? I have also tried with `@Inject` from `javax.inject` with same result.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use Spring as the component model for the mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public abstract class DeviceDataMapper {
    ...
}
```

That way you can inject dependencies into it (e.g. other hand-written it uses) as well as inject the mapper into other classes instead of resorting to the `INSTANCE` pattern.

Comment: Are there any advantages to using the spring component model approach vs the instance pattern?

Answer (score 8):

In order for `@Autowired` to work, the `DeviceDataMapper` class needs to be a Spring bean. It will not work if you instantiate it yourself.

Either make it a Spring bean and use it like one, or pass a reference to `deviceService` into it from your controller.

Comment: I would also recommend to use Spring as the component model for the mapper: @Mapper(componentModel="spring" public abstract class DeviceDataMapper { ... }. That way you can get it in injected (the generated implementation will be a Spring bean) instead of resorting to the `INSTANCE` pattern.

Comment: @Gunnar this should be a standalone (and accepted) answer. [Reference](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.1/reference/html/index.html#using-dependency-injection)